# Chrome extension sends browsing information

Tags: chrome

When visiting a url in Chrome, I saw in Fiddler, after the responses, calls to:

```
http://api29.datarating.com/related
http://api29.datarating.com/service2
```

For example after going to http://www.google.com

I have this in Fiddler: http://api29.datarating.com/service2

with body:

> e=Y3oweE56azNKbTFrUFRJeEpuQnBaRDF5VlRselNXeHhVRXBWZEU1bGNWa21jMlZ6Y3oweE9ESTJOakEwT1RNMU16UXdOVGd6TkRBbWMzVmlQV05vY205dFpTWnhQV2gwZEhCekpUTkJMeTkzZDNjdVoyOXZaMnhsTG1SbEx5VXpSbWRtWlY5eVpDVXpSR04wY213bE1qWmxhU1V6UkRZNFNWcFZOV1kwU25OVFdDMUJZbEZ6TkVkUlEwRWxNalpuZDNOZmNtUWxNMFJqY2lad2NtVjJQV2gwZEhCekpUTkJMeTkzZDNjdVoyOXZaMnhsTG1SbEx5WjBiWFk5TkRBd01pNHhKblJ0WmoweEpuTnlQV2gwZEhCekpUTkJMeTkzZDNjdVoyOXZaMnhsTG1OdmJTOD0%3D

which is Base64, decoded to another Base64 string:

> cz0xNzk3Jm1kPTIxJnBpZD1yVTlzSWxxUEpVdE5lcVkmc2Vzcz0xODI2NjA0OTM1MzQwNTgzNDAmc3ViPWNocm9tZSZxPWh0dHBzJTNBLy93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmRlLyUzRmdmZV9yZCUzRGN0cmwlMjZlaSUzRDY4SVpVNWY0SnNTWC1BYlFzNEdRQ0ElMjZnd3NfcmQlM0RjciZwcmV2PWh0dHBzJTNBLy93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmRlLyZ0bXY9NDAwMi4xJnRtZj0xJnNyPWh0dHBzJTNBLy93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8=7

which decodes to:

> s=1797&md=21&pid=rU9sIlqPJUtNeqY&sess=182660493534058340&sub=chrome&q=https%3A//www.google.de/%3Fgfe_rd%3Dctrl%26ei%3D68IZU5f4JsSX-AbQs4GQCA%26gws_rd%3Dcr&prev=https%3A//www.google.de/&tmv=4002.1&tmf=1&sr=https%3A//www.google.com/;

that obviously contains the URL I just visited.

By enabling and disabling the extensions in Chrome, I found that it was the extension:

**SpeakIt! 0.2.91**

[Web Store Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speakit/pgeolalilifpodheeocdmbhehgnkkbak)

```
**Is this allowed / legal?**
```

The question should have been **Can we block this or are their extensions to check other extensions ?**  as pointed out.

I see some solutions :

Analyze the code of the extension with https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/

Use an 'Adblock' kind of strategy with disconnect me https://disconnect.me/

Browser privacy modes. etc

Comment: Might be related: http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/01/malware-vendors-buy-chrome-extensions-to-send-adware-filled-updates/

Comment: Ok thanks, but it is still not clear if it is legal from the article.

Comment: maybe little comment for down vote ?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but your question boils down to "Is it legal for browser extensions to send my browsing data to a server?", which is not really a technical question, and can be answered with "well, it depends…"

Comment: Well, every country has its own laws so you should at least specify "is this legal in Australia"? Or whatever. I think that legal issues can definitely be tightly related with computer security, though I upvoted your question, despite areeing with @JoelL that being put like that, the question is hardly going to be answered.

Comment: This extension tracks navigation failures and sends them to a tracking company. See [js/stats.js](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/issues/4#issuecomment-37042310).

Comment: @Lekensteyn helpfull extension no I can see what the other paramters are and analyze extensions.

Comment: And the datarating.com servers are called from js/similar.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For protecting your privacy, you could use another `Open Source` addon which protects you from the various tracking methods employed in today's method. The link to download is below :-

https://disconnect.me/

I am also currently using this addon, nice tool, save bandwidth, secures wifi, loads pages faster etc.

Also, the main feature that it completely eliminates the trackers so that the bandwidth is also saved. It also very nicely visualizes the blocking it is doing along with detailed information.

Furthermore, you can also protect your privacy by opening the web pages in the `Icognito` or the `Private Browsing` mode of your browser as by default in the Private Browsing mode, the addons are disabled and hence no tracking of your web page visiting atleast by the addons.

Comment: Are you sure it also forbids separate extensions to sending out your data? Just wondering.

Comment: @Dakatine - I am not sure about that it forbids the separate addons as well, but for other things it works pretty well. That is why I also suggested of using the Private Browsing mode :)